# Angular Material Table Asynchronously Load Data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material table that I am using to display data from an API call. The API returns a lot of data. In an effort to make the application interactive faster and more efficient, we have implemented paging. For example, the initial call retrieves 5 records and renders the table. We are then making subsequent calls to get the rest of the data. We are updating the datasource by adding the returned data and re-rendering the table with the returned data.

The initial data is retrieved using a resolver (for performance purposes). I then run a method in oninit...

```
getTimecardSynch() {
    // Number of records to retrieve
    const pageSize = 5;
    // Call to method...passing in pageSize and pageNumber
    this._timecardManagementService
      .getIncrementalSubmittedTimecards(pageSize, this.pageNumber)
      .subscribe(
        (timecardResponse) => {
          // Increment pageNumber
          this.pageNumber++;
          // Update table datasource with retrieved data
          this.addRowData(timecardResponse);
          // Test whether pageSize is equal to the number of records returned.
          // If true, there are probably more records to retrieve and call needs made again.
          if (pageSize === timecardResponse.length) {
            // Make call to retrieve timecards again
            this.getTimecardSynch();
          } else {
            // Set the dataNotLoaded boolean to false so the interface is changed
            this.dataNotLoaded = false;
            // Show the snackbar message to the end user
            this.openSnackbar('All Timecards Loaded', '', '');
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      );
  }
```

As you can see from the above code, I have a method called "addRowData" where I pass the returned data from the API call. Here is the method...

```
  addRowData(row_obj) {
    // Add the retrieved data from the row_obj parameter to the datasource array
    this.dataSource.data.push(...row_obj);
    // Re-render the table rows
    this.table.renderRows();
    // Reload the table
    this.updateTable(this.timecards);
  }
```

So I am wondering if there is a better way to possibly asynchronously tie this together? My concern is that the data being retrieved is altered by another user while this process is running and results in perhaps a duplicate row, etc.

Comment: retrieving 5 records at a time seems extremely small. have you considered something like retrieving 100 records at a time and then only display 5 at a time with paging?

Comment: Retrieving 5 records is very small. We are trying to account for our client base, which some of them are located in areas where broadband is next to nil. We wanted a small call initially to get interactivity asap. As we have worked on this, one thing we have changed is that we have altered the backend call to allow for the ability to retrieve the rest of the records. As for pagination, we are using that in the material table. We were trying to solve the performance issue with getting the data back and rendering. This is why I wondered if there was a better way to asynchronously render.

Comment: maybe do some performance testing, but my guess is that bringing back 5 records and bringing back 100 records will take about the exact same amount of time.

Comment: @Rick It does take the same amount of time, but bringing back the five getts the user interface more interactive sooner.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure that is possible. 99% of the time is your network http call. once you have the data, executing a split on your array is going to take less than 1000th of a second. a lot less.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. No need to push the data in this.dataSource.data because at a time will 
   display the requested data only(means based on pagination)
2. Use public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(timecardResponse);
3. No need to call any method like this.addRowData(timecardResponse);
```

Comment: 1) Why wouldn't I need to push the recently returned data from the API to the local datasource array? Just to define paging...we have paging on the API side via url variables. On the client side, I have pagination enabled in the Material Table.
2) I am using...( dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ITimecard>;). Are you saying that with each call, I would reinitialize the datasource variable? How does that solve the issue?
3) Are you saying that you would integrate the push and render into the get method and not have it separate? If so, I understand that, but doesn't solve my issue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If the same data is received twice due to some change in observable, you can try `distinctUntilChanged` operator in rxjs. This operator will make the observable only emit value if the current value is different from the last.

```
const incrementalSubmittedTimecards$ = this._timecardManagementService
  .getIncrementalSubmittedTimecards(pageSize, this.pageNumber).pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

incrementalSubmittedTimecards$.subscribe(...);
```

If you want to have a time interval between two successive emissions and get only the latest data, you can try `debounce` operator in rxjs. this operator will not take into account any value emitted within specified time and consider only the latest value at the end of specified time.

```
const incrementalSubmittedTimecards$ = this._timecardManagementService
  .getIncrementalSubmittedTimecards(pageSize, this.pageNumber).pipe(debounce(() => timer(1000)));

incrementalSubmittedTimecards$.subscribe(...);
```

Correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Thanks...I will keep those techniques in mind. I was successfully able to implement it with 5 and then the rest. I just wondered if there was a better way.